# GL_DRAW/READ_FRAMEBUFFER vs GL_FRAMEBUFFER?

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I've noticed that there now are the GL_DRAW/READ_FRAMEBUFFER extensions. Currently I am simply using GL_FRAMEBUFFER and glTextureBarrierNV. However, I have not found that much about the READ/WRITE extensions and thus have some questions.

What OpenGL version were they introduced?
What advantages do they give over using simply GL_FRAMEBUFFER for both read and write?
Where can I find more info about this?

Comment: Do you mean the `GL_DRAW/READ_FRAMEBUFFER` binding points?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pedantic note: `GL_DRAW/READ_FRAMEBUFFER` were not introduced in an extension; they are core OpenGL 3.0 functionality. Yes, technically this functionality is also exposed in ARB_framebuffer_objects, but that is a [core extension](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Extensions#Core_Extensions) and it is still core GL 3.0.

In any case, if you want the etymology of the `DRAW/READ` distinction, you need to look to [EXT_framebuffer_blit](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/framebuffer_blit.txt). That is where those enumerators originated, and that is *why* those enumerators exist. Instead of just specifying two FBOs to blit from/to, they created two context binding points for framebuffers. The `glBlitFramebuffer` command blits from the currently bound `READ_FRAMEBUFFER` to the currently bound `DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`.

If you are not using blit, then you don't really *need* the `DRAW/READ` distinction. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use it however. `glReadPixels` reads from the `READ_FRAMEBUFFER`. Binding to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` binds to both points, so your code can still work. But it is sometimes useful to have an FBO binding which can be read from that doesn't interfere with drawing operations.

Answer (score 5):

In case you mean the `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` and `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` constants, these come from the [EXT_framebuffer_blit](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/framebuffer_blit.txt) extension, which was later made core in OpenGL 3.0 and into a special [ARB_framebuffer_object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt) extension (together with `EXT_framebuffer_multisample` and the original `EXT_framebuffer_object`, of course) for versions <3.

They allow you to bind separate FBOs for reading and drawing operations. This is especially useful for the FBO to FBO copy operations introduced by `EXT_framebuffer_blit` (which allow you to copy data directly from one FBO to another) and for the resolving of multisampled FBOs introduced (and needed) by `EXT_framebuffer_multisample`, which actually builds ontop of the afore mentioned blit extension. When binding an FBO to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`, you actually bind it to both `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` and  `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`.

Like said all these FBO extension were made core in OpenGL 3.0, but may also be available to earlier versions. Look [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) for more information.